# Can't find fantasy story read before at a library in the late 90s

Tags: story-identification

In the late 90s I borrowed a fantasy book from my local library call the tailsman or maybe the cup I'm not sure and haven't been able to find it myself. It was about this woman from Michigan or maybe Indiana wakes up one morning in a fantasy world. She meets this guy who convinces her to try this contest where the winner gets given a cup i think. When she sings even the trees aprove of her making her the winner gaing the cup?. That night in the tavern one of the wenches come in to take care of her needs at this it is discovered that she isn't a man but a woman and the guy she met earlier tries to get her disqualified because she was pretending to be a man but since she never claimed to be a man she was allowed to keep the award. Then he ask if she had been celibate for a year because that was a tradition also. Also i remember the world didn't use edged weapons for some reason and there were at least 2 books in the series thank you for your help in advance

Comment: There's no end of fantasy novels called "the talisman"; https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=talisman&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: As chance would have it, I asked about this one a few years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be *Cup of Clay*, by Carole Nelson Douglas.  It's the first book (of 2) in the Taliswoman series, although I see some references to the series as a trilogy, so it may have been shortened or unfinished. It came out in '91 so the timing is good. The blurb from Goodreads lines up pretty close with your description.

> Minnesota reporter Allison Carver finds herself in the Land of Veil, where beautiful streams run with poisonous water and glorious fields mask hideous decay. Here, women are treated with great homage — and great disdain; here, children are loved — except for those who are cast away.

> Alison's only guide to Veil is Rowan, a quarrelsome hero on a quest for the Cup of the Earth — a talisman that is won by song and song alone. But when Alison inadvertently plucks it from his grasp, her life, the lives of the Littlelost, and the life of the Land of Veil itself hang in the balance.

Comment: Thank you that was it